# ARDL model: Is it valid the use of Wald test on short-run coefficients to determine causality?

Tags: granger-causality, ardl, wald-test

I estimated an ARDL model and there was cointegration based on bound tests. I obtained the error correction form. Most journal articles I have seen assess sort-run causality by just performing Granger causality tests which are done apart from ARDL. However my sample is small and the number of regressors relatively large (that is why I chose ARDL). After a quick search in internet I found one article stating that Wald tests can be used for joint significance of the short run coefficients of one given variable. But I have not found any paper indicating how to determine short-run causality in ARDL. Does anyone can clarify this? Suggestions of empirical published papers on the field of economics are welcomed

Comment: Hi: The paper at this link probably doesn't answer the question you asked but one of its references might. In particular, I would check out the one by Bewley, 1979. https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/28020/1/507401956.PDF

Comment: very much thank you for the quick reply. it helped but the issue is still not clear for me, unfortunately

Comment: it seems the topic hasn't been very discussed too much despite the popularity of ARDL

Comment: yes. I've used the ARDL and I never heard of bounds tests. Pesaran definitely works on topics that are on the edge. I'm sorry it didn't help that much.